# How to avoid "fake" ids creation in db?

Tags: python, postgresql

I have python code which push new record to db to column info.

```
   try:            
        db.add_new_record(info)
    except Exception as e:
        log.error(e)            
        db.db.rollback()
        continue
```

I use standard sql query

```
INSERT INTO mydb (info, desc) VALUES ('value1', 'value2')
```

python:

```
import psycopg2
def add_new_record(self, info):
    info['table'] = self.table
    query = "INSERT INTO {table} (c1, c2)  VALUES ('{val1}', '{val2}')".format(**self.make_dct(info))
    self.make_execute(query)
    self.db_commit()
    return True
```

Sometimes I see exception

```
 exception: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "mydb_info_key"
```

It's normal.

I count rows in db: 25000 records.
But my last ids start with 60000+.

`Duplicate exception` records new id? How to avoid this?

Comment: What does your table definition for `mydb` look like ?

Comment: @fixatd  Data type: character varying, Lenght: 1024, Scale: empty, Collation: pg_catalog."default", statistics: -1, Storage: Extended

Comment: Unique Constraint public.mytable_mycolumn_key auto

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there is another table `mydb_seq` that tells sql what the next index to use is(you can look at what it is with `SELECT * FROM mydb_seq;`)

somewhere else you are actively setting an ID to a higher value than this pointer, so sometimes this pointer points at an index that already exists in your table

you can identify where using the following logic

first find the pointer for the next_id

```
SELECT * FROM mydb_seq;
```

then query your table for anything with a bigger id

```
SELECT id FROM mydb WHERE id > $next_id;  // replace $next_id... with the value from above
```

as an aside you should really *really* **really** use the cursor.execute variable insertion ... what you are doing now is madness that will get you sql injected

```
qry = "INSERT INTO {table} (field1,field2,field3) VALUES (%s,%s,%s)".format(table="my_db")
cursor.execute(query,(var1,var2,var3))
```

Comment: yes I do:      def make_execute(self, query):
        self.cursor.execute(query)

Comment: no you dont ... you are doing normal string substitution It looks like to me

`query = "INSERT INTO {table} (c1, c2)  VALUES ('{val1}', '{val2}')".format(**self.make_dct(info))` is going to get you hacked

Comment: Sorry! You are right about vars, thanks.  I'll try your answer, thanks a lot!